# Метод, который можно вызвать для всех Activity

Tags: android

Как лучше всего сделать метод который можно вызвать из любой Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте свой класс. В нем, например, статичный метод. И вызывайте его откуда хотите.

```
class MyMethods{
public static method(){
}
}
```

Теперь из любой активити вызывайте этот ваш метод

```
MyMethod.method();
```